# Hard Define Custom Field Value

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

Is it possible to hard define a custom field value with a function?

As in, no matter what WordPress will always set the value of 'some_meta' => 'this'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly grabbing the meta, wrap it in a function, then you can provide a default, or, comment out the innards and just return "this"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I believe this is working the way I intended